# getting "ksh: no space"-error when running a unix command

Tags: shell, unix, aix

I have a text file `WIDeletion2.txt` whose sample text is as follows.

```
$ head WIDeletion2.txt
5A1E7DF7C1C8BC4497FE3AD68954EF21 VA_ITSHOME
294A07B8ABDC454FABD0CD488B3FA51B VA_ITSHOME
C15A689952E4A14993B4787020258AEA VA_ITSHOME
C3E8CFE6FFBD3A45B37336D270940AC8 VA_ITSHOME
F69955919630784EB41FE8D0BE2A260F VA_ITSHOME
DD044FFD70FDED46AEA9205DA3435B24 VA_ITSHOME
0C678B5BC6531140BE92F40A0B727012 VA_ITSHOME
```

It contains around 90k of lines like this. I want to add `deletedwob` at starting of each line and `" y y"` (without quotes) at the end of each line.

I am trying to achieve this doing the following (on AIX):

```
$ for i in `cat WIDeletion2.txt`
> do
> echo deletewob $i y y >> WIDeletion3.txt
> done
ksh: no space
```

I am getting a `ksh: no space` error. I have verified the space of `/tmp` as well. There is around 600mb of space available and the size of `WIDeletion2.txt` is as below.

```
$ ls -ltr WI*
-rw-rw-r--    1 fnsw     fnusr       3390146 Apr 10 10:50 WIDeletion2.txt
```

`df` for mount `/tmp` is:

```
$ df -m /tmp
Filesystem    MB blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/hd3        1024.00    615.37   40%     1601     2% /tmp
```

So by adding those extra stuffs to file it can go to twice or thrice of its size which would be at max 20 mb and I have 600 mb space available. I even tried putting it in a script and then running the script which yields the same error. Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell is running out of memory processing that loop.
Try:

```
sed -e 's,^,deletedwob ,' -e 's,$, y y,' WIDeletion2.txt > WIDeletion3.txt
```

Comment: Thanks this did work. but what do you mean by shell running out of memory. Is specific amount of memory for shell if so  how much is it, and how we can check it.?

Comment: You would need to check the `ulimit -a` output and see how much stack space is allocated for user processes. e.g. from an AIX machine: `stack size (kbytes, -s) 32768`. Max memory (-m) size may also affect when your processes run out of space.  For @BMW's answer, his shell method is not using the `for` loop with backticks.    When using the backticks, the shell may be saving all that output on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

/tmp folder is opened for all.

using sed

```
sed 's/.*/deletedwob& y y/' WIDeletion2.txt > WIDeletion3.txt

deletedwob5A1E7DF7C1C8BC4497FE3AD68954EF21 VA_ITSHOME y y
deletedwob294A07B8ABDC454FABD0CD488B3FA51B VA_ITSHOME y y
deletedwobC15A689952E4A14993B4787020258AEA VA_ITSHOME y y
deletedwobC3E8CFE6FFBD3A45B37336D270940AC8 VA_ITSHOME y y
deletedwobF69955919630784EB41FE8D0BE2A260F VA_ITSHOME y y
deletedwobDD044FFD70FDED46AEA9205DA3435B24 VA_ITSHOME y y
deletedwob0C678B5BC6531140BE92F40A0B727012 VA_ITSHOME y y
```

Using awk

```
awk '{printf "deletedwob%s y y\n",$0}' file
```

Using shell

```
while read -r line; do echo "deletedwob${line} y y"; done < file
```

Comment: Your last method about using shell, even i was trying to do using shell only, but i used for loop for that, what is the difference between this one and mine as for my method it said no space and using while it did work. But both method uses shell only.